# How to pass a reference through a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<class Fun, class... Args>
void foo(Fun f, Args... args)
{
    f(args...);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 1000;

    foo([](int &b, int a){ b = a; }, b, a);
    std::printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Currently it prints `1000`, that is, the new value of `b` gets lost somewhere. I guess that's because `foo` passes the parameters in the parameter pack by value. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By using reference :

```
template<class Fun, class... Args>
void foo(Fun f, Args&&... args)
{
    f( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

Comment: This will fail if `a` is an rvalue, even though that should be semantically permissible. `&&` would be better I think.

Comment: Perfectly fits my needs if `&&` is used.

Comment: You should forward: `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: @GMan : +1 I was going to suggest some use of `forward<>` here as well, but I didn't know the syntax for forwarding a parameter pack. :-[

Answer (score 8):

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class Fun, class... Args>
void foo(Fun f, Args... args)
{
    f(args...);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 1000;

    foo([](int &b, int a){ b = a; }, std::ref(b), a);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```